# Is it possible to sort form fields with CKEDITOR and tinysort?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, tinysort

I have it sorting but the data disappears and the fields are not longer active.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer ...If anyone else runs into this just use the divarea plugin for ckeditor.